# How can I check if a MySQL table exists with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

As simple in theory as it sounds I've done a fair amount of research and am having trouble figuring this out.

How can I check if a MySQL table exists and if it does do something. (I guess a simple php if/else statement could work for this)

Is there a way to do this?

This is what I have done with cwallenpoole's response:

```
mysql_connect("SERVER","USERNAME","PASSWORD");
mysql_select_db('DATABASE');

$val = mysql_query('select 1 from `TABLE`');

if($val !== FALSE)
{
   print("Exists");
}else{
   print("Doesn't exist");
}
```

Comment: Please read my benchmarks below before making a final answer.

Comment: Note that if you are trying to check if a table exists for the purposes of adding it if it doesn't exist you can use a query like `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS \`my_table\``

Answer (score 85, accepted):

```
// Select 1 from table_name will return false if the table does not exist.
$val = mysql_query('select 1 from `table_name` LIMIT 1');

if($val !== FALSE)
{
   //DO SOMETHING! IT EXISTS!
}
else
{
    //I can't find it...
}
```

Admittedly, it is more Pythonic than of the PHP idiom, but on the other hand, you don't have to worry about dealing with a copious amount of extra data.

### Edit

So, this answer has been marked down at least twice as of the time I am writing this message. Assuming that I had made some gargantuan error, I went and I ran some [benchmarks](http://pastebin.com/7SbjVEYx), and this is what I found that my solution is over 10% faster than the nearest alternative when the table does not exist, and it over 25% faster when the table does exist:

```
:::::::::::::::::::::::::BEGINNING NON-EXISTING TABLE::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
23.35501408577 for bad select
25.408507823944 for select from schema num rows -- calls mysql_num_rows on select... from information_schema.
25.336688995361 for select from schema fetch row -- calls mysql_fetch_row on select... from information_schema result
50.669058799744 for SHOW TABLES FROM test
:::::::::::::::::::::::::BEGINNING EXISTING TABLE::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
15.293519973755 for good select
20.784908056259 for select from schema num rows
21.038464069366 for select from schema fetch row
50.400309085846 for SHOW TABLES FROM test
```

I tried running this against DESC, but I had a timeout after 276 seconds (24 seconds for my answer, 276 to fail to complete the description of a non existing table).

For good measure, I am benchmarking against a schema with only four tables in it and this is an almost fresh MySQL install (this is the only database so far). To see the export, look [here](http://pastebin.com/icWFpf0b).

### AND FURTHERMORE

This particular solution is also more database independent as the same query will work in PgSQL and Oracle.

### FINALLY

`mysql_query()` returns FALSE for errors that aren't "this table doesn't exist".

If you need to guarantee that the table **doesn't** exist, use `mysql_errno()` to get the error code and compare it to the relevant [MySQL errors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-errors/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html).

Comment: I tried your example but am having trouble with it (See example in edited question)

Comment: Have you called mysql_select_db?

Comment: Ok, I see what's going on. `!== FALSE` means the table exists (answer updated). Here's what I have as a test:`mysql_select_db('test', $c);if(mysql_query( 'SELECT 1 FROM foo' ) !== FALSE) echo 'foo';if(mysql_query( 'SELECT 1 FROM bar' ) !== FALSE) echo 'bar';` foo does not exist, bar does. I get 'bar' output to the browser.

Comment: Awesome thanks! This seemed to work beautifully and fast. I'm going to have several thousand tables so this will probably be PERFECT! I'm not sure why you recived so many down votes, you explained this well and so I +1 this. Thanks again!

Comment: +1 Your answer looks like it's the most complete and have done the most research

Comment: There, I've bounced it into positive +1's again.

Comment: @j-j-kim While I agree `mysql_query` is a tad dated, that was the original function I used when I wrote the answer and it is the same function that the pastebin code uses. For consistency I'd prefer to keep as is.

Comment: As a note: This also happens to be how Drupal handles things.

Comment: `mysql_query()` returns false on error, so please check the error before assuming that false means "table doesn't exist". Error code 1146 and 1051 are the codes to check for "unknown table": https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html

Comment: I fail to see why people are obsessing over what should amount to insignificant performance differences, for a question which wasn't asking for the fastest way.

Comment: that should be {{{select 1 from `table_name` limit 1}}}

Comment: This question still receives a fair amount of traffic, it would be nice if you added the LIMIT 1.  This will reduce your Benchmark times down to well below 1 millisecond for about a 150,000 (1,500,000%) on your best case number of 15 mS vs. 0.000125mS,  see my last year post for Profiling results.

Comment: I've been looking for solutions like this, but I'd like to add that you shouldn't use MySQL as it's deprecated and it may not work. You should consider migrating to MySQLi.

Comment: The `mysql_` library was standard at the time of authoring this answer. I believe the bug in INFORMATION_SCHEMA has been updated to make the numbers above less relevant, though the answer continues to be effective.

Comment: This produces an error message when the table doesn't exist. I prefer a clean solution.

Answer (score 36):

The cleanest way to achieve this in PHP is to simply use DESCRIBE statement.

```
if ( mysql_query( "DESCRIBE `my_table`" ) ) {
    // my_table exists
}
```

I'm not sure why others are posting complicated queries for a such a straight forward problem.

### Update

**Using PDO**

```
// assuming you have already setup $pdo
$sh = $pdo->prepare( "DESCRIBE `my_table`");
if ( $sh->execute() ) {
    // my_table exists
} else {
    // my_table does not exist    
}
```

Comment: This is the slowest solution of all.

Comment: @MichalM thank you for your insightful comment. Let's play the game called 'put your money where your mouth is'. 

I will not even mention the fact that you should be caching results anyways but let's continue. Shall we?

Comment: @AlekseyKorzun What queries are you running?

Comment: "Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead"

Comment: @IberoMedia the question was for mysql_* extension and is from 2011.... you can use the same approach with mysqli_*.

Comment: @AlekseyKorzun Could you provide your actual tests (and MySQL version)?

Comment: @AlekseyKorzun this should be the accepted answer. It works great, thanks. Using mysqli, btw. The accepted answer doesn't make any sense, since it would need to also check the error code to make sure it was due to the inexistence of the table. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '$databasename' AND table_name = '$tablename';");
```

If no records are returned then it doesn't exist.

Comment: How can I check if a record was returned?

Comment: Please check my benchmarks as this does not seem to be the fastest

Answer (score 12):

SHOW TABLES LIKE 'TableName'

If you have ANY results, the table exists.

**To use this approach in PDO:**

```
$pdo         = new \PDO(/*...*/);
$result      = $pdo->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tableName'");
$tableExists = $result !== false && $result->rowCount() > 0;
```

**To use this approach with DEPRECATED mysql_query**

```
$result      = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tableName'");
$tableExists = mysql_num_rows($result) > 0;
```

Comment: MySQL Documentation suggest looking at the schema information

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably too old school from the 3.23 days :)

Comment: How can I check for a result?

Comment: @NathanRomano Documentation doesn't mean we're limited. By doing -> `$table_exists =  $pdo->query( 'SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tableName' ); var_dump( $table_exists );` This output `true` if the table exist, false otherwise.

Comment: I like this approach

Answer (score 11):

### 125 microsecond table exists check

### .000125 sec. (125µs)

```
mysql_unbuffered_query("SET profiling = 1");  // for profiling only

@mysql_unbuffered_query("SELECT 1 FROM `table` LIMIT 1 ");
if (mysql_errno() == 1146){

 // NO EXISTING TABLE CODE GOES HERE

}
elseif(mysql_errno() > 0){

  echo mysql_error();    

}

$results = mysql_query("SHOW PROFILE");  // for profiling only
```

Execution time, measured using mysql profiling, when a table exists, or not, is about **.000125 sec. (125µs)**

The LIMIT 1 is important for speed.  This minimizes the Sorting Result and Sending Data query State times. And table size is not a factor.

I always use an unbuffered query when no results are required.

PROFILE RESULTS 
**WHEN TABLE DOES NOT EXIST**

```
QUERY STATE           SECONDS   
--------------------  -------
starting              0.000025  
checking permissions  0.000006  
Opening tables        0.000065  
query end             0.000005  
closing tables        0.000003  
freeing items         0.000013  
logging slow query    0.000003  
cleaning up           0.000003  
TOTAL                 0.000123  <<<<<<<<<<<< 123 microseconds
```

**WHEN TABLE EXISTS**

```
QUERY STATE           SECONDS   
--------------------  -------
starting              0.000024
checking permissions  0.000005
Opening tables        0.000013
System lock           0.000007
init                  0.000006
optimizing            0.000003
statistics            0.000009
preparing             0.000008
executing             0.000003
Sending data          0.000019
end                   0.000004
query end             0.000004
closing tables        0.000006
freeing items         0.00001
logging slow query    0.000003
cleaning up           0.000003
TOTAL                 0.000127 <<<<<<<<<<<< 127 microseconds
```

Answer (score 10):

```
mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM yourDB");
//> loop thru results and see if it exists
//> in this way with only one query one can check easly more table
```

or `mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE 'tblname'");`

Don't use `mysql_list_tables();` because it's deprecated

Comment: that would be a lot of iterating if you have 500+ tables

Comment: This is in the php documentation too: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php

Comment: @Nathan: someone who has 500 tables doens't ask how to check this

Comment: @Nathan: You can tack on a LIKE '<tablename>' as well.

Comment: @kevmo: never use that. This function became deprecated.

Comment: @yes123 I guess it depends on the application, maybe Pete is trying to see if a table exists in a scheme before executing an update script or something.

Comment: @yes123: Yeah I know, but the query is there on that page, which is what Pete was asking for.  A quick Google search brings up that page from which you can just read the query.

Comment: @kevmo: it's deprecated you can't use that. I guess there aren't any excuses

Comment: @yes123: You're missing what I'm trying to say.  On that page it clearly says "It is preferable to use mysql_query() to issue an SQL SHOW TABLES [FROM db_name] [LIKE 'pattern'] statement instead.", so anyone reading that page would realize "Oh hey I can call mysql_query() with that SQL statement."  I'm not giving an excuse, in fact, I never said to use that _function_, I said to use the _query_ listed on that page.

Comment: @kevmo: ah ok now i got it.. didn't read properly your comment lol sorry

Comment: How do I check if the result is true when using "SHOW TABLES LIKE"?

Comment: Please check my benchmarks as this does not seem to be the fastest

Comment: `SHOW TABLES` can also be run by itself, without any additional parameters, to get a list of all tables, that can be searched using PHP.

Answer (score 8):

Even faster than a bad query:

```
SELECT count((1)) as `ct`  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_schema ='yourdatabasename' and table_name='yourtablename';
```

This way you can just retrieve one field and one value.  .016 seconds for my slower system.

Comment: I like this one the best, just a quick easy 'yes/no' is all I want.

Comment: You can also check for multiple tables:
SELECT count((1)) as `ct`  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_schema ='yourdatabasename' and ( table_name='yourtablename' or table_name='yourtablename1' or table_name='yourtablename2' );

Answer (score 4):

It was already posted but here it is with PDO (same query)...

```
$connection = new PDO ( "mysql:host=host_db; dbname=name_db", user_db, pass_db );

if ($connection->query ("DESCRIBE table_name"  )) {
    echo "exist";
} else {
    echo "doesn't exist";
}
```

Works like a charm for me....

And here's another approach (i think it is slower)...

```
if ($connection->query ( "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'db_name' AND table_name ='tbl_name'" )->fetch ()) {
    echo "exist";
} else {
    echo "doesn't exist";
}
```

You can also play with this query:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM db_name LIKE 'tbl_name'
```

I think this was suggested to use in the mysql page.

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT USE MYSQL ANY MORE. If you must use mysqli but PDO is best:

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $pdo); // proper PDO init string here
if ($pdo->query("SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'")->fetch()) // table exists.
```

Comment: Not a good idea to use `mysql` for new projects where PHP version is 5.5.0 or above.  `Deprecated` means might cease to exist in future versions of PHP.

Comment: Yeah, the function no longer exists as of 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","php_sample_login_register"); 

if ($connection){
        echo "DB is Connected <br>";
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE user(
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
            name VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(255)NOT NULL,
            password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
            );";
        if(mysqli_query($connection,$sql)) {
            echo "Created user table";
        } else{
            echo "User table already exists";
        }
    } else {
        echo "error : DB isnot connected";
    } ?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use

show tables where Tables_in_{insert_db_name}='tablename';

Answer (score 0):

You can use many different queries to check if a table exists. Below is a comparison between several:

```
mysql_query('select 1 from `table_name` group by 1'); or  
mysql_query('select count(*) from `table_name`');

mysql_query("DESCRIBE `table_name`");  
70000   rows: 24ms  
1000000 rows: 24ms  
5000000 rows: 24ms

mysql_query('select 1 from `table_name`');  
70000   rows: 19ms  
1000000 rows: 23ms  
5000000 rows: 29ms

mysql_query('select 1 from `table_name` group by 1'); or  
mysql_query('select count(*) from `table_name`');  
70000   rows: 18ms  
1000000 rows: 18ms  
5000000 rows: 18ms
```

These benchmarks are only averages:

Comment: This is clearly now an answer to this question. Even so, why don't you explain what you are doing, on each example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer