# SELECT 1 FROM table, weird print_r result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

From what I have read, when executing the following sql command and fetchAll() on my table with 6 rows and 11 columns:

```
$sql = "SELECT 1 FROM table";
$sqlPrepared = $conn->prepare($sql)
$sqlPrepared->execute()
$result = $sqlPrepared->fetchAll();
$print_r($result);
```

I should be getting 6 rows of just one value in each row, with the value 1 inside each of those values. However, I am getting 6 rows of two values in each row, with the value 1 inside each of those values:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
    [1] => 1 
    [2] => 1 ) 
  [1] => Array ( 
    [1] => 1 
    [2] => 1 ) 
  [2] => Array ( 
    [1] => 1 
    [2] => 1 ) 
  [3] => Array ( 
    [1] => 1 
    [2] => 1 ) 
  [4] => Array ( 
    [1] => 1 
    [2] => 1 ) 
  [5] => Array ( 
    [1] => 1 
    [2] => 1 ) 
)
```

**QUESTION 1:** Why am I getting 2 values for each array instead of just 1?

**QUESTION 2:** Instead of the inner arrays being

```
 Array ( 
    [1] => 1 ...
```

why doesn't it start from [0]?:

```
 Array ( 
    [0] => 1 ...
```

Comment: 1 should be the column name or do you mean `*`?

Comment: @aldrin27 1 is not the column name. "SELECT 1 FROM", it is a commonly used sql technique, which output is giving me almost what I expected it to, the value of "1" for each row that is found, however I am getting 2 columns of "1" for an odd reason.

Comment: I think 1 checks whether it exists or not. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171041/what-does-it-mean-by-select-1-from-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't provide any flag on [`->fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) method, this includes the associative and numeric indices on the multidimensional array row.

So when you used `SELECT 1 FROM`, the associative index is `1` (meaning, column name is `1`), and since array keys are unique, the numeric index adjusted, the numeric index with the value pair is assigned to `2`.

Comment: interesting, and is there a reason the associative index started from 1 and not 0? convention? random decision by php team?

Comment: @Webeng nope, the column name is `1`, from your query `SELECT 1 FROM whatever_table_name`

Comment: @Webeng sure glad this helped