# How can i check for a table without errors being displayed

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I want to check if a table in the OpenCart database exist so i made this function

```
public function CheckCustomer(){
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'customer_online');
return $query->row;
}
```

and in my controller i test if it exists i set a variable to 1 or 0 depending.

The table does exist everything is fine, byt if i delete the c from customer just to simulate the table not being there my tpl page is not rendered instead i get this error :

Notice: Error: Table 'OpenCart-Test.oc_ustomer_online' doesn't exist
Error No: 1146
SELECT * FROM oc_ustomer_online in /home/justine/www/opencart-test/opencart-1.5.5.1/upload/system/database/mysql.php on line 50

Is there anyway of doing this without it throwing errors on screen as i need to know if the table exists before i display certain information in my tpl file.

Hope someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: Please, look on similar topics [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432178/how-can-i-check-if-a-mysql-table-exists-with-php) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008299/check-if-mysql-table-exists-or-not)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking dynamically-created tables are a bad idea. Any table you need should *always* exist, and you can simply use `TRUNCATE TABLE mytable` to quickly remove all rows rather than `DROP TABLE`.

**edit: way better idea than below**
Change the query to `SHOW TABLES FROM my_database` [or simply `SHOW TABLES` if the db is already selected] and check to see if the table name you're looking for exists in the result set.

---

That said, you should be able to suppress the error by prefixing the function with `@`, ie:

```
$query = @$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'customer_online');
```

Or you should be able to switch your mySQL database object to use Exceptions rather than PHP Errors, then enclose the function call in a `try{ } catch() { }` block.

Comment: Didn't work sorry. The reason i need to test is that earlier versions of Opencart pre 1.54 dont have the table customer_online .

Comment: @JustineSmithies you'd probably be better served using the [`VERSION`](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/index.php) var declared in OpenCart rather than a call to a deprecated function.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved .

Putting this in my controller file fixed it.

```
$this->data['checkcustomer'] = @mysql_query ('SELECT * FROM '.DB_PREFIX.'customer_online');
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL can list all tables in a database. By specifying a "like tablename" you can search for a specific table.

```
/**
 * Check if the table 'customer_online' exists
 * @return boolean TRUE if table exists, FALSE otherwise.
 */
public function CheckCustomer(){
    $res = $this->db->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".DB_PREFIX."customer_online'");
    return (boolean) $res->num_rows;
}
```

This does not generate any errors as it is not trying to access the table, just looking for the table name in the list of tables in the database.