# PHP check to see if MySQL table exists

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to see if a table already exists and then act accordingly. I was unable to solve my problem from viewing previous posts.I'm aware of a secondary problem where the sql throws an error but I don't know why it throws. When I replace $thisTable with the actual string, it works. But my primary problem is not being able to detect if the table exists.

```
$thisTable = "testX";
$thisTable = preg_replace("/[^A-Z,a-z,0-9]/", '', $thisTable);
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE ".$thisTable;
    //I get an SQL error here?
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $isThere = $stmt->num_rows;
    if ($isThere > 0){
        echo "Already exists."
    } else {
        echo "Doesn't exist."
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>WITH QUERY: " . $sql;
}
```

Comment: Do you even Google? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432178/how-can-i-check-if-a-mysql-table-exists-with-php

Comment: Yes, I saw that, among others. But isn't all the mysql_ deprecated? Just looking for a little help learning this stuff.

Comment: It is deprecated but `mysqli_` functions should work just fine. There are also PDO based solutions in that question.

Comment: Hint: how are strings to be handled in MySQL? And the table name is just a string at this `where like...` query.

Comment: Fook me. I found it in that post. Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the table name in the query.

```
$sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$thisTable'";
```